# pChart a graph for each row

Tags: php, database, pchart

I'm new at using pChart. I take data from database to construct the graph.

I will have a random number of rows and I would like to do a graph for each row.
(one row -> one graph). Is it possible?

So far I can do the graph but all the rows are in the same graph.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include("pChart/class/pData.class.php");
include("pChart/class/pDraw.class.php");
include("pChart/class/pImage.class.php");
include("pChart/class/pPie.class.php"); 

$myData = new pData(); 

$Requete = "SELECT * FROM `day`"; 
$Result = mysql_query($Requete, $db);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
    $hour = explode(" ", $row["g1"]);
    $nb = $row["numb"] * 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++){
        if ($i%2 == 1){  
            $time[$i] = ($hour[$i])/ 60;    
            $myData->addPoints($time[$i],"year"); 
        }else{ 
            if ($hour[$i] == "00"){
                $name[$i] = "On";
            }elseif ($hour[$i] == "02"){
                $name[$i] = "Off";
            }
            $myData->addPoints($name[$i],"name");
        }
    }
}

$myData->setAbscissa("name");
$myData->setSerieDescription("year","Application A"); 
$myPicture = new pImage(600,300,$myData);  
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"pChart/fonts/tahoma.ttf","FontSize"=>16));  
$PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$myData);  
$PieChart->draw3DPie(340,125,array("DrawLabels"=>TRUE,"Border"=>TRUE)); 
$myPicture->autoOutput("images/example.png");   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want a picture for every row? In that case I think that you will have to include the lower part of your code (starting from $myData to $myPicture) in the while loop.